# Apache Beam Splittable DoFn Streaming API

Tags: java, python, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have been working on a data streaming use case where an API that is called with a GET returns a stream of Json data, streaming in the response body.
Moreover the API is able to share the data stream if there is multiple clients requesting the stream like Adobe Livestream [1].

I would like to build a scalable Dataflow that will scale with the volume returned by such an endpoint.

In order to do that the documentation led me toward Splittable DoFn. which seems to be the new way to develop a new IO connector vs UnboundedSources API
After spending some time getting comfortable with the principle behind SDF and analysing Kafka and file watch implementation.

I do struggle to identify what should be my restriction in that scenario.

I have various scenarios in mind but none of them seems to comply with SDF and the fact that restriction should be a finite representation of the work represented by the element it is paired with and support splitting.
A streaming API does not have byte ranges nor offsets that are really convenient in message brokers.

What do you think ? What would you consider as a restriction ?

[1] https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/live-stream-api/getting_started.md#

Comment: I don't know much about the streaming API, but I know SplittableDoFns excel at splitting work that can be parallelized. Is it possible to open multiple connections to the JSON data stream to increase throughput by reading elements in parallel? If so, is data distributed deterministically or randomly somehow?

Comment: If it is fully random and there is no possible space to place restrictions on, then your restriction can just be counts of elements read, like so: `[count, max]`. You could make max either represent an unbounded restriction, or a bounded restriction. That way your unbounded restrictions will continuously read elements, but they can be split into bounded restrictions that only read N elements before finishing. That way you can scale up by splitting when there's a lot of work, and eventually those restrictions will finish and scale back down.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to open multiple connections so that your consumer adapts to the data-stream throughput. Of course the producer API needs to handle data stream splitting. Data can be distributed deterministically in a best effort way based on an ID or randomly.

Comment: That is a very good point, if i understand correctly, my RestrictionTracker would be a GrowableOffsetRangeTracker where offsets are element counts

Comment: I hadn't heard of GrowableOffsetRangeTracker before, but it seems like exactly what you need. If you get it working I encourage you to come back to this and leave an answer, I would be interested in how it worked!